# dc maxon motor control

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello
I am a new user in ROS and i want to build my robot. I have two DC maxon motors with 150 w power and two arduino uno boards. Is it possible for me to control my base with ros_arduino_python package??
I think i need some extra controller like Pololu but i am not sure. Does anyone do this before???
I really appreciate anyone who could help me:))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189183/dc-maxon-motor-control/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. As noted on the [ros_arduino_bridge wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_arduino_bridge?distro=hydro), you need the recommended Pololu motor shield and the encoder shield.

The [README](https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge/tree/hydro-devel) for Hydro goes into more detail about the hardware and wiring that is required.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0